# How does Spring Cloud Config download remote configurations for a service?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

I have found this [example](https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example) about spring-cloud on GitHub a few days ago.

I am having some problems getting the config service example working. I don't know how to use `config-microservice` correctly.

[in this blog](http://www.kennybastani.com/2015/07/spring-cloud-docker-microservices.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuqTMZKXonjHpfsX57ukoWaC0lMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ATcdqI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFQ7LMMaZq1rgMXBk%3D),it said configurations for your microservice applications should be stored in the environment and not in the project.

But I'm not sure how to do this. I don't know how one of the microservices, for instance a `movie-microservice` Spring Boot application gets a config file from `config-service`.

Comment: i have a example . https://github.com/hanmin-github/spring-cloud-demo . in this example demo1-service how to use demo1.yml in https://github.com/hanmin-github/loving-config ?

Comment: what exactly is your problem here? Read docs http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html, try to configure it, keep it simple - you dont have to start for example with discovery service from the very beginning.

Comment: hey @freakman, i have readed this docs , there is a config like this (spring.cloud.config.uri: http://myconfigserver.com) . I added the configuration in my project. but it don't work . my project only use loction configuration and didn't go to the remote reading configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

First and foremost, make sure that `spring-cloud-starter-config` is on the class path of your applications that want to use remote configuration from a config service.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_client_side_usage

The best way to understand whether or not the config service is correctly serving the environment configurations for an application is to enable health check.

On your config service configuration, make sure to enable the following for one of your applications. I've added a health check for the `movie` service, with a label of `master` (indicating to use the master branch of my git repository).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-microservice-config
        health:
          repositories:
            movie:
              label: master
```

Now all that I need to make sure of is that my git repository has a configuration available for my application with the name `movie`. The name of this configuration could be `movie.{properties|yml}`. I've chosen to use yaml: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-microservice-config/blob/master/movie.yml

Now after you've started your config service, you can run a health check to see if the remote repository is being used.

`$ curl http://localhost:8888/health`

This will return the following response:

```
{
  "status" : "UP",
  "configServer" : {
    "status" : "UP",
    "repositories" : [ {
      "sources" : [ "https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-microservice-config/movie.yml", "https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-microservice-config/application.yml" ],
      "name" : "movie",
      "profiles" : [ "default" ],
      "label" : "master"
    } ]
  },
  "discoveryComposite" : {
    "description" : "Spring Cloud Eureka Discovery Client",
    "status" : "UP",
    "discoveryClient" : {
      "description" : "Spring Cloud Eureka Discovery Client",
      "status" : "UP",
      "services" : [ "configserver" ]
    }
  },
  "diskSpace" : {
    "status" : "UP",
    "total" : 498954403840,
    "free" : 445484142592,
    "threshold" : 10485760
  },
  "hystrix" : {
    "status" : "UP"
  }
}
```

Now in the movie service, make sure the following configuration is set in `bootstrap.yml`.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: movie
  profiles:
    active: default
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
    failFast: true
```

Now start your movie service, making sure first that the config service is running and available at `http://localhost:8888`, and the remote configuration will be used for the specified profile.

Comment: Very detailed, think you very much ! To solve my problem !